# поиск значения в mongoose по нескольким ключам

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, node-modules

У меня есть схема вида:

```
{
  firstName: { 
    type: String,
    default: 'none'
  },
  lastName: { 
    type: String,
    default: 'none'
  }
}
```

И мне надо выбрать запись, у которой `firstName` или `lastName` равны `none`. Возможен ли поиск с выборкой "одной записи" с проверкой в обоих полях?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or):

```
YourSchema.find({ $or:[ {'firstName':'none'}, {'lastName':'none'} ] }, 
  function(err, docs) {
    // docs - массив со всеми найденными объектами, 
    // для которых выполнится хотя бы одно условие
});
```